# Using Luke to analyze my Hibernate Search query DSL

Tags: lucene, hibernate-search, luke

How do I use Luke to analyze my Hibernate Search query DSL?

I have the following Hibernate Search query DSL:

```
QueryBuilder qb = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(User.class).get();
  qb.bool().should(qb.keyword().onField("name").matching(searchQuery).createQuery())
     .should(qb.keyword().fuzzy().withPrefixLength(1).onField("description").matching(searchQuery).createQuery());
```

What's the easiest way to transform this into Lucene query so I can analyze the query using Luke:

[image]

I also have other more complex Hibernate queries that I would want to analyze using Luke.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried calling `toString` on the created Lucene query? This should give you are pretty good starting point for the query you need to generate in Luke.